# Aura iteration does not update the View after array Update?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

My lightning component's controller has an array named newResources and using aura:iteration to show a table based on the values in it.
There is a method in js "removeNewResourceColumn" which removes one element from that array and then the aura:itration updates the view with one less row
but when the method removes the last element of array the aura iteration view is not getting updated.

E.g. 
If I have 8 records in the array then the table will show 8 rows.
If removeNewResourceColumn removes 6th element the table will show 7 records
but if removeNewResourceColumn removes 8th element the table still shows 8 records.
Has anyone ever faced this problem?

Here is the code snippet

Lightning Component

```
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped">
        <tbody>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.newResources}" var="newResource" indexVar="index">
            <td data-label="FirstName">
                <div class="slds-truncate">
                    <div class="slds-form-element__control" style="width:95%">
                        <div aura:id="nameField" class="slds-show">
                            <ui:inputText class="slds-input" value="{!newResource.FirstName}" placeholder="" disabled=""/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            //It has more columns like first name
        </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Controller:

```
var RecordIndexStr = event.getSource().get("v.value");
var RecordIndexInt = parseInt(RecordIndexStr);
var newResources = component.get("v.newResources");

newResources.splice(RecordIndexInt, 1);

component.set("v.newResources",newResources);
```

Comment: Can you add your minimal required code in your question by editing it so that community can have look what's going wrong with that?

Comment: Hey, @sanketkumar Added the code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you have to use

> component.set("v.newResources",
>   JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newResources));

Before setting that value.

In aura iteration we have to change the reference to memory to reflect the changes.

Or you can use ***slice*** function which returns a new array

```
newArray = newResources.slice(1, LengthofArray);
component.set("v.newResources", newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly declare `newResources` as an Aura Attribute in your component ?

You should have `<aura:attribute name="newResources" type="List"/>` within your component.

Comment: Yes it is declared that is why it is working for the removal of any start or mid element.

Answer (score 0):

On what basis are you deciding whether you want to delete 1st or 8th element in the list??
Keep in mind that List is based on zero-based indexing, so if you want to refer to last element then Size of the list minus 1 will give you last element.